# Xgboost Regresion tree

Tags: regression, boosting

I am building a boosted regression tree in R and I use the simple xgboost function from the package xgboost in R.

```
xgboost(data=insample, label=df$y[insampleinds], nrounds = 1000)
```

I have data for around 1 million observations for 5 features or independent variables (x1 to x5). I do get good out of sample performance. I am interested in computing the sensitivity of my response y to the independent variables. To do this I:

1) Randomly and with replacement sample from the distribution of say x1(keeping x2 to x5 fixed), and create a simulated vector of x1

2) Compute the response y from the tree output at this simulated x1 vector

I find that the results from step 2 seem to change from run to run, for instance every time I build a new tree, I would get a new response y (the tree output) for my simulated set of x1.

Would anyone know how to deal with this issue or an alternate method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely to observe different fits during multiple runs because the random no. generator is in a different state every time you start the training.

I would recommend that you set a random seed before every training run to the same specific value, this will improve repeatability:

```
set.seed(101)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I would expect to observe a variance on the results of step 2 depending on the sensitivity of response y to x1.
If x1 is white noise, then the expected out of sample performance should not change that much after your shuffle. On the other hand, if x1 is highly correlated with y, shuffling or changing the distribution of p(y|x1) would introduce a high bias to the result of step 2. This means that if you repeat step 2 several times, you would observe higher variance.